# Parsing xml to string in java to give a value of priority in sitemap.xml

Tags: java, xml, servlets

In my websites root directory, a java servlet is ready all the files after content/falcon/en/index and creating a sitemap.xml

```
  <url>
<loc>https://www.ded.com/</loc>
<lastmod>2019-08-29</lastmod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>0.9</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>https://www.ded.com/eFNOL/eFNOL_Login?SO=01</loc>
<lastmod>2019-08-29</lastmod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>0.9</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>https://www.ded.com/customerselfservice/CSSU</loc>
<lastmod>2019-08-29</lastmod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>0.9</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>
https://www.dede.com/claims/roadside-assistance/
</loc>
<lastmod>2019-08-29</lastmod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>0.9</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>https://www.dede.com/payments/</loc>
<lastmod>2019-08-29</lastmod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>0.9</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>https://www.ded.com/insurance/</loc>
<lastmod>2019-08-29</lastmod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>0.9</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>https://www.dede.com/home/</loc>
<lastmod>2019-08-29</lastmod>
<changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
<priority>0.9</priority>
</url>
```

I have this method  in java writing the sitemap.xml

```
public void createXMLNode(Document document, Element rootElement, SlingHttpServletRequest request, Iterator<Page> pageIterator) {
        Element headElement = document.createElement("url");
        Element locElement = document.createElement("loc");
        Element lastModElement = document.createElement("lastMod");
        Element changefreqElement = document.createElement("changefreq");
        Element priorityElement = document.createElement("priority");

        Node locElementNode = locElement;
        Node lastModElementNode = lastModElement;
        Node changefreqElementNode = changefreqElement;
        Node priorityElementNode = priorityElement;

        Page childPage = pageIterator.next();
        locElementNode.setTextContent(request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName() + childPage.getPath());
        LOG.error("childPage.getLastModified()" + childPage.getLastModified());
        if(null != childPage.getLastModified()) {
            Date date = childPage.getLastModified().getTime();
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
            try {
                dateFormat.parse("2019-07-15");
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            lastModElementNode.setTextContent(dateFormat.format(date));
        }

        changefreqElementNode.setTextContent("weekly");
        priorityElementNode.setTextContent("0.9");

        rootElement.appendChild(headElement);
        headElement.appendChild(locElementNode);
        headElement.appendChild(lastModElementNode);
        headElement.appendChild(changefreqElementNode);
        headElement.appendChild(priorityElementNode);

        Iterator<Page> childPageIterator =  childPage.listChildren();
        while(childPageIterator.hasNext()) {
            createXMLNode(document, rootElement, request, childPageIterator);
        }
    }
```

AS you can see the 0.9 is hardcoded for priority 
i wrote this program in java that gives priority value by the number of backslashes in a string

```
public class StringArray {
    public static void main (String[]args){
        int count = 0;
        double priority=0;
        String [] array = {"https://www.farmers.com/", "https://www.farmers.com/css/login/","https://www.farmers.com/auto/" ,"https://www.farmers.com/customerselfservice/CSSU"   };
        for(int i =0;i<array.length;i++){
            for(int z = 0;z<array[i].length();z++){

                if(array[i].charAt(z) == '/')
                 {    
                count++;   
            }


            }

            System.out.println(count); 


        if (count == 3){
            priority=1;
        }

        else if(count==4)
        {
            priority = 0.9;
        }
        else if(count==5)
        {
            priority = 0.8;
        }
        else if(count==6)
        {
            priority =0.7;
        } 
        System.out.println("<priority>" + priority +"</priority>"  );
        count =0;
        }




    }
}
```

How can i integrate my priority value algorithm with this java method. I have to parse the loc value to a string and therefor i can do comparisons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add following methods to set the priority:

```
public static String getPriority (String location){
    switch(countSlashes(location)){
        case 3: return "1";
        case 4: return "0.9";
        case 5: return "0.8";
        case 6: return "0.7";
        default: return "0.0"; //or whatever prio in default case
    }
}

//replace everything except '/' to get count of slashes easily
private static int countSlashes(String location) {
    return location.replaceAll("[^/]", "").length();
}
```

You could then call `getPriority` from your `createXMLNode` method like shown below:

```
.....

String location = request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName() + childPage.getPath();
locElementNode.setTextContent(location);
....

priorityElementNode.setTextContent(getPriority(location));

....
```

Comment: hello i get back all 0.0 for all priority values ? not sure why using your code

Comment: nevermind its working perfectly , had much more backslashes in my test data

Comment: Can you print the location string and see how it look like? or post it here? How does your loc node look like?

Comment: might have some more questions on xml java in the future

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58418063/using-java-if-a-certain-string-is-read-do-not-write-that-whole-child-root-eleme

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58418063/using-java-if-a-certain-string-is-read-do-not-write-that-whole-child-root-eleme

Comment: can you look at my other question